# Error while installing eclipse neon android development

Tags: eclipse, installation, failed-installation

I've been trying to install eclipse neon on my PC which has windows 10 64 bits.

I get the following error while installing:

[image: picture]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You probably don't have permissions to install there, try to run the installer as administrator. (right click executable -> run as administrator)

Answer (score 1):

try installing as Administrator